# Excel Macro Text to Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write "macro" for my .csv files. I need to perform first on data "text do columns", but when I tried to record macro I get an error:

"too many line continuation".

I select collumn A and then pressed "text to Columns".

Code of macro:

```
    Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination := Range("A1"), DataType := xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier := xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter := FALSE, Tab := FALSE, _
        Semicolon := FALSE, Comma := TRUE, Space := FALSE, Other := FALSE, FieldInfo _
        := Array(Array(1,1),Array(2,1),Array(3,1),Array(4,1),Array(5,1),Array(6,1), _
        Array(7,1),Array(8,1),Array(9,1),Array(10,1),Array(11,1),Array(12,1),Array(13,1 _
        ),Array(14,1),Array(15,1),Array(16,1),Array(17,1),Array(18,1),Array(19,1),Array _
        (20,1),Array(21,1),Array(22,1),Array(23,1),Array(24,1),Array(25,1),Array(26,1), _
        Array(27,1),Array(28,1),Array(29,1),Array(30,1),Array(31,1),Array(32,1),Array( _
        33,1),Array(34,1),Array(35,1),Array(36,1),Array(37,1),Array(38,1),Array(39,1), _
        Array(40,1),Array(41,1),Array(42,1),Array(43,1),Array(44,1),Array(45,1),Array( _
        46,1),Array(47,1),Array(48,1),Array(49,1),Array(50,1),Array(51,1),Array(52,1), _
        Array(53,1),Array(54,1),Array(55,1),Array(56,1),Array(57,1),Array(58,1),Array( _
        59,1),Array(60,1),Array(61,1),Array(62,1),Array(63,1),Array(64,1),Array(65,1), _
        Array(66,1),Array(67,1),Array(68,1),Array(69,1),Array(70,1),Array(71,1),Array( _
        72,1),Array(73,1),Array(74,1),Array(75,1),Array(76,1),Array(77,1),Array(78,1), _
        Array(79,1),Array(80,1),Array(81,1),Array(82,1),Array(83,1),Array(84,1),Array( _
        85,1),Array(86,1),Array(87,1),Array(88,1),Array(89,1),Array(90,1),Array(91,1), _
        Array(92,1),Array(93,1),Array(94,1),Array(95,1),Array(96,1),Array(97,1),Array( _
        98,1),Array(99,1),Array(100,1),Array(101,1),Array(102,1),Array(103,1),Array(104 _
        ,1),Array(105,1),Array(106,1),Array(107,1),Array(108,1),Array(109,1),Array(110, _
        1),Array(111,1),Array(112,1),Array(113,1),Array(114,1),Array(115,1),Array(116,1 _
        ),Array(117,1),Array(118,1),Array(119,1),Array(120,1),Array(121,1),Array(122,1) _
        ,Array(123,1),Array(124,1),Array(125,1),Array(126,1),Array(127,1),Array(128,1), _
        Array(129,1),Array(130,1),Array(131,1),Array(132,1),Array(133,1),Array(134,1)
End Sub
```

How can I solve this problem ?

---

### ----------------------- EDIT ----------------------------

I tried to change code as you suggest:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination := Range("A1"), DataType := xlDelimited, TextQualifier := xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter := FALSE, Tab := FALSE,  Semicolon := FALSE, Comma := TRUE, Space := FALSE, Other := FALSE, FieldInfo _
        := Array(Array(1,1),Array(2,1),Array(3,1),Array(4,1),Array(5,1),Array(6,1), Array(7,1),Array(8,1),Array(9,1),Array(10,1),Array(11,1),Array(12,1),Array(13,1),Array(14,1),Array(15,1),Array(16,1),Array(17,1),Array(18,1),Array(19,1) _
End Sub
```

BUt after tried to save it, I get an error "Compile error: invalid character at last lin of Array(19,1)_"

I tried to delete _  but it was same error.

Comment: Please read my EDIT.....

Comment: you need to keep blank/white space before underscore which you are missing. You have to have it like this: `) _` or `, _` or `; _`!!

Comment: yes I tried, but I get same error now pointed to Sub Macro2()

Comment: let's make it clear- your edit in Macro2 is not a complete sub?? what I presented in my answer is only a part of your very long original code. I took only six of your lines and make them compacted to show how it works. You need to do the same with all, complete code of yours. You don't need to compact everything into 2 lines. Try compact two consecutive lines into one but for complete code!!

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking this "Array()" is just few lines and collumns so if I don't use it then macro will selected less collumns and lines...

So I need to go with those arrays to which number ? I normall just select collum A and then pressed "Text to Columns". My .csv files are different sizes, one has 1000 lines another one 10000....

Comment: it could works as you expect but you have to make it correctly, set beginning and the end of array which you are missing: `Array(Array(1,1), Array(2,2))`

Comment: Hmm, I understand what you wan tto explain me, but if you take a look to my first post you will se there is no form like Array (Array(1,1), and then Array(2,2)).... and is still working. It's always just Array(X,1).

Comment: ok, possibly what you need is to switch into ADO (ADODB) technique of retrieving data from  text files. Quite easy, reliable, very popular, and will make that kind of problems you have now.

Comment: your fields have different data types? I mean if it is just the same, you can exclude it. What matters is the delimiter. You only need to complete field info if one field is `Text`  then the other is `Date`  and another is `General` etc. If not, exclude it. See my post.

Comment: Np, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're data type is ther same for each field, you can just use this:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:= Range("A1"), DataType:= xlDelimited, Comma:=True
```

I think that should do it?
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

`Too many lines continuation` refers to characters which you will find at the and of most of the lines inside the code you presented: `_` (underscore). What you need to do is to compact the code by adding some of the lines into the other.

**In other words- you need to have less lines of code but make them longer.**

Example:

```
'instead of this part of your code:
Selection.TextToColumns Destination := Range("A1"), DataType := xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier := xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter := FALSE, Tab := FALSE, _
    Semicolon := FALSE, Comma := TRUE, Space := FALSE, Other := FALSE, FieldInfo _
    := Array(Array(1,1),Array(2,1),Array(3,1),Array(4,1),Array(5,1),Array(6,1), _
    Array(7,1),Array(8,1),Array(9,1),Array(10,1),Array(11,1),Array(12,1),Array(13,1 _
    ),Array(14,1),Array(15,1),Array(16,1),Array(17,1),Array(18,1),Array(19,1),Array _
    '...etc

'you should try to compact it in this way:
Selection.TextToColumns Destination := Range("A1"), DataType := xlDelimited, TextQualifier := xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter := FALSE, Tab := FALSE,  Semicolon := FALSE, Comma := TRUE, Space := FALSE, Other := FALSE, FieldInfo _
    := Array(Array(1,1),Array(2,1),Array(3,1),Array(4,1),Array(5,1),Array(6,1), Array(7,1),Array(8,1),Array(9,1),Array(10,1),Array(11,1),Array(12,1),Array(13,1),Array(14,1),Array(15,1),Array(16,1),Array(17,1),Array(18,1),Array(19,1),Array _
'...etc
```

**IMPORTANT**
When doing this please be sure that you left (empty) space before underscore at the end of each lines. You need to have something like:

```
...) _
..., _
....), _
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this code Which prompts the user to select a range then it applies the text to column feature. Note: Parameter values may change depending on the data set that your working with. -> [Source Link](https://sites.google.com/site/exceldriven/excel-programming-templates/excel-vba-library-samples/texttocolumns)

```
Sub TextToColumnsRangeSelection()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim MySelection As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set MySelection = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select your range", Title:="Select Range", Type:=8)

    MySelection.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=MySelection, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=True, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=False
End Sub
```